# Unable to access viewcontroller from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when app launches

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am having an issue where I am unable to access a function in my viewcontroller.swft file when lunching from a killed app in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

I am trying to access the function with `viewController?.loadRequestnotificationwaiting(for: url as! String)` from AppDelegate which I pass data to the viewcontroller where I can do some stuff. But when I place an alert in the function in the viewcontroller `loadRequestnotificationwaiting`. The data is not being passed.

Now I use this same method in other areas to pass data to the viewcontroller from the appdelegate and they work fine. It seems to not work when using it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Is the viewcontroller not available yet when trying to access it from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
class AppDelegate : UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    weak var viewController : ViewController?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.observeReachability()
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        registerForPushNotifications()

        // opened from a push notification when the app is closed
        if let userInfo = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let object = userInfo["aps"] {
                let url = object["url"]

                viewController?.loadRequestnotificationwaiting(for: url as! String)
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    func loadRequestnotificationwaiting(for notification_url_wait : String) {
        notification_url_final_wait = notification_url_wait

        let url = URL(string: notification_url_final_wait!)
        let URLrequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webView.load(URLrequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `viewController` set?

Comment: You should see it at the top of my code `weak var viewController : ViewController?`

Comment: That declares it, but it doesn't assign a value to it, so it will be `nil`. You probably want the `rootViewController` from your application's `window` property

Comment: I use this same method in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and it works with those

Comment: So your code assigns a value to the app delegate `viewController` property somewhere, but that happens later than `didFinishLaunching`.

Comment: No it happens at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. That is when the value is sent to the viewcontroller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186244/discussion-between-paulw11-and-cesar-bielich).

Answer (score 2):

You are relying on your `AppDelegate`'s `viewController` property, but you are setting this property in your `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller;  This is fine when a notification is received when your app is already running, since the `viewController` property is already set.

When a notification causes your application to be launched, the `viewController` property is *not set* and the function isn't called.

Assuming that the view controller you need is the initial view controller from your storyboard, you can get the root view controller from your app delegate's `window` property;

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    ConnectionManager.sharedInstance.observeReachability()
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    registerForPushNotifications()

    // opened from a push notification when the app is closed
    if let userInfo = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String : AnyObject] {
        if let object = userInfo["aps"],
            let url = object["url"] as? String,
            let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
                viewController.loadRequestnotificationwaiting(for: url)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: App crashes when the notification comes in from a closed state on the app `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: You need to ensure that you aren't force unwrapping things that may be `nil`.  Handling notifications in a view controller may not be the best approach; The view controller may not be loaded when your app receives a notification and it isn't in the foreground.  If you do use the view controller, be prepared for outlets to be `nil`.

Comment: I am not necessarily handing the notification in the viewcontroller. I am doing that in the FirebaseMessagingService. I am just sending the url in the payload to the viewcontroller so I can load that url in my webview

Comment: whats your opinion on sending the url through intent and LocalBroadcastManager?

Answer (score 0):

1. if your view controller is root, you can summon it by call  `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!` or overwrite it with your `viewController`
2. you can raise a notification using `-[NotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]` and observe this notification name in View Controller